# How do I create the GodMode folder in Windows 7 & Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, godmode

How do I create the GodMode (AKA *[Windows Master Control Panel shortcut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Master_Control_Panel_shortcut)* and *All Tasks*) folder in Windows 7?

Comment: More explanations about the so-called "GodMode", from the How-To geek: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8711/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-the-secret-how-to-geek-mode-in-windows/

Comment: Keep in mind that people reported having problems with this trick, like explorer crashing on startup, and having to remove the folder from a safe-mode command-line.

Comment: yep, there are known issues with GodMode (i like Windows-In-A-Box much better anyway), see the warning here: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2010/01/05/windows-7-god-mode/#

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create a new folder on the desktop (or anywhere else) and rename it like below:

```
GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

**It works for Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 as well...**

[image]

> It's a folder packed with shortcuts to
>   just about every settings change and
>   administrative function in Windows 7.
>   Everything you'll find in the Action
>   Center, Backup and Restore, Autorun,
>   Desktop Gadgets, Devices and Printers
>   -- it's all there. All dumped in one central location for easy access.

Note: You can use any name you want *before* the dot.

Comment: oooo nifty. +1.

Comment: Works for Vista as well +1

Comment: Is there a similar mode for XP?

Comment: XP doesn't need it. All this is is your control panel - it's just exposing the stuff BEHIND the search functionality. XP didn't have that.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there a similar mode for XP?

No, but you can use **[Windows In A Box](http://www.big-daddy-design.com/windowsinabox.htm)**. The categorized pull-down menus allow even easier access to even more functions.

[image]

It's also available as **[Windows 7 In A Box](http://www.big-daddy-design.com/windows7inabox.htm)**.

*Windows In A Box comes as a stand-alone executable, no installation is required.*

You may rename *Window`s In A Box.exe* into *GodMode.exe*, if you want to :)

Comment: @Molly7244 When I try to click on either link, I get a balloon pop-up saying "High risk website blocked".

Answer (score 6):

Besides the commonly known 'god mode' there are other similar solutions. The approach is the same as with GodMode: create a folder on the desktop and rename it to Name.{GUID}. Where Name can be anything you wish. A list of GUIDs is below:

```
GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
{00C6D95F-329C-409a-81D7-C46C66EA7F33}
{0142e4d0-fb7a-11dc-ba4a-000ffe7ab428}
{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}
{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}
{1206F5F1-0569-412C-8FEC-3204630DFB70}
{15eae92e-f17a-4431-9f28-805e482dafd4}
{17cd9488-1228-4b2f-88ce-4298e93e0966}
{1D2680C9-0E2A-469d-B787-065558BC7D43}
{1FA9085F-25A2-489B-85D4-86326EEDCD87}
{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}
{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}
{241D7C96-F8BF-4F85-B01F-E2B043341A4B}
{4026492F-2F69-46B8-B9BF-5654FC07E423}
{62D8ED13-C9D0-4CE8-A914-47DD628FB1B0}
{78F3955E-3B90-4184-BD14-5397C15F1EFC}
```

Comment: @MadBoy: Would you be more specific on what `Name` meant?  GodMode can be anything? or GUID can be anything?

Comment: GodMode can be anything. Like MyLink.{...}  etc

Comment: You should provide labels for the unlabeled GUIDs. It's not really helpful to see one by itself. Anyways, this page is helpful, since this is where the registry comes into play: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144096(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Meet the **[GodMode Creator](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/godmode-creator-windows-7-vista-released)**:

> We are pleased to release GodMode
>   Creator for Windows 7 & Vista. GodMode
>   Creator is a freeware utility which
>   lets you create 38 “GodModes” in
>   Windows 7 & Vista with a click.

[image]

> There is nothing magical about the
>   GodMode. Windows has a set of certain
>   folders which are identified by unique
>   strings referred to as CLSID or
>   Windows Class Identifiers. These
>   folders can be accessed by using the
>   CLSID identifier codes that Windows
>   assigns to each individual folder in
>   the Windows Registry. If you know the
>   codes, you can launch these with ease.
>
> In short, GodModes are nothing but
>   developer shortcuts built into Windows
>   7 & Vista, that enable easy access to
>   certain settings and information about
>   the operating system.
>
> Using GodMode Creator, you can create
>   these shortcuts easily. Simply click
>   on the desired button and it will
>   create the Special Folder or
>   “GodMode”.

Comment: Your original link <del>is dead</del> <i>doesn't allow cross-site linking</i> try pointing it to the article: http://beingpc.com/2010/01/god-mode-creator-launched/ or the publisher's page would be a better link point: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/godmode-creator-windows-7-vista-released  Thanks for the afterthought.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather have the God Mode command in the desktop context menu, here is a set of steps for doing it:

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-add-windows-7-god-mode-shortcut-in-desktop-context-menu/

It's an alternative to setting it up as a folder.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the next GodMode maker (this one lets you choose from over 50 "Deities" :)

**Be A Windows God With Go GodMode**

> As you probably know, GodMode provides
>   quick access to an operating system's
>   more or less hidden controls (Windows
>   Vista/Seven). How does that work? You
>   have to create a folder with a certain
>   string (GUID) at the end.
>
> But that can be pretty hard and, even,
>   unaesthetic. Why? Well, it can get
>   pretty hard to create a lot of them
>   (considering the large number of
>   GodModes out there). Furthermore, that
>   GUID doesn't look very nice on your
>   desktop.
>
> This is where **[Go GodMode](http://apps.nozavi.com/go-godmode-overview)** enters the
>   scene: This small app will help you
>   create over 50 GodModes just by
>   selecting them and pressing the GO
>   button. It also provides a few cool
>   options:
>
> Instead of creating the folders on
>   your desktop, you can create them in a
>   folder on your computer and just
>   create a shortcut on your desktop. You
>   can also add shortcuts to the Start
>   Menu, QuickLaunch and Favorites
>   folder.
>
> You can add GodModes to folder and
>   desktop context menus without even
>   adding a single file or folder to your
>   harddrive!

[image]