# Who discovered GodMode and the GUID?

Tags: windows-7, windows, godmode

This is NOT the same question as this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/91645/how-do-i-create-the-godmode-folder-in-windows-7)

I'm trying to be as specific as I can, otherwise the superpolice will close it again and I get slapped. :(

So, onto the question: this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330741%28VS.85%29.aspx 
does not list that GUID that opens up the "GodMode" so my question remains, how and who found it.

Thanks, you are all awesome.

Comment: you know that link isn't exhaustive of all GUIDs and their interpretations under Win7, right?  (downvote wasn't me...)

Comment: Perhaps it's because any question that leads off with emphasis of its difference from one that was just Closed, doesn't sit well.  Also, you might consider fixing your 0% Accept Rate.  Just sayin'.

Comment: +1 ... simply because the downvoter doesn't have the guts or the decency to leave a comment why he or she dislikes the question.

Comment: So you give him 8 rep instead of a measly -2? haha

Comment: The previous time you asked this the question was deleted because you were rude. Now it's being closed. Reason: **Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question remains ... who found it?

Lee at **[downloadsquad.com](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/01/03/stupid-windows-7-trick-unlock-the-secret-god-mode-folder/)**, who was one of the first to report on it, credits the "guys at **[windows7themes](http://windows7themes.net/windows-7-enable-secret-godmode.html)**".

you may ask further questions there.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly hidden.  It's a documented development feature which means that it wasn't found by anyone but released as part of the Windows 7 documentation on MSDN.