# Is there a way to enable "god mode" in Windows 8, like you could in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8

I am looking for a way to enable God-Mode in Windows 8, does anyone know how to do this or is it even possible?

It's a trick that [lets you access all system's controls in one folder](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-10423985-285/understanding-windows-7s-godmode/).

Comment: The related question for Windows 7: [How do I create the GodMode folder in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/91645/how-do-i-create-the-godmode-folder-in-windows-7)

Comment: I believe it's called "Super Control Panel" in Windows 7.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You just do the same on Windows 8.

1. Go to Desktop.
2. Create a new folder.
3. Rename it to GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}

Comment: This is really cool

Comment: Or even "ILikePuppies.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}" [See this.](http://brandonlive.com/2010/01/04/the-so-called-god-mode/)

Comment: It doesn't matter what it's called as long as it ends in `.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}` (WITH leading period (.))

Comment: It also doesn't matter where it is. I prefer not to have anything on the desktop.

Comment: Regardless of what you use before the GUID (ILikePuppies, GodMode, etc.)... create it in or move it to the \Windows folder, then create a shortcut (Send to Desktop) and rename that to whatever you want. No need to look at that GUID all the time.

Comment: The folder can be created in Windows 10, too, but it will not have a visible name.

Answer (score 48):

There is a built in God mode, from the Start Screen type **settings**

you will get a selection on the right, select **settings** , there will be 90 or more settings available. Use the scroll bar at the bottom to see all of them

[image]

.

[image]

Comment: Search for just `a` and you get 294! :/

Comment: Start screen search is very powerful tool overlooked by most.

Comment: Or search for anything you would have searched in the "god mode" folder. It's exactly the same list.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of Administrative tools can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: @Lucifer, thanks for the edit, I was on my mobile device when answering :)

Comment: That's actually accessible with left-clicking the bottom left corner. It has most of what pne needs from a classic start menu, programs excluded. If it only had that, start menu would be unneeded.