# Name won't show on GodMode folder on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

After [creating the GodMode folder](https://superuser.com/a/495664/494173), the folder has no visible name, even though what I entered before the dot was `GodMode`.

[image: GodMode icon]

What I named the folder was `GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`.

Is there a way to get a display name to show up for this special folder in Windows 10?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3ghx7a/how_to_enable_godmode_in_windows_10/

Comment: Just did the steps from this earlier link, but Windows refuses to give it a display name. I can however safely rename the folder without breaking the godmode.

Comment: @LPChip And it keeps your name? Mine doesn't.

Comment: It does if you create a folder, put a desktop.ini in it with the right content and use attrib to set the right permissions to the folder and file.

Comment: Post an answer with the desktop.ini content. Nothing in the link you commented has anything about changing the folder name using the ini file.

Comment: The problem is that after you use the desktop.ini method, the folder is still blank and renaming has no effect. So I did a better thing, posting an answer that its not possible. I suspect Microsoft introduced a bug here, or they want to discourage the use of the GodMode folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is a bug/feature, and its currently not possible to give that folder a name.

Comment: Yeah, I can't get a single setting of `desktop.ini` to work on it, either. Maybe there's something in the registry that needs to be changed?

Comment: you need to attrib desktop.ini +s +h and the folder +s before it will work.

Comment: I did. It doesn't change anything. I couldn't change the tooltip, and I couldn't change the icon. I also found that it's impossible to edit the registry values for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to create a shortcut on the desktop with the following target value:

```
explorer shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

Name it whatever you like! :)

To change the icon to the Control Panel icon, click the `Change Icon` button in the shortcut properties, then enter `%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll` into the `Look for icons in this file` box. Then scroll through the icons until you find the Control Panel "monitor with pie chart" icon.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ahmad Addas's answer, here's some lines of Powershell that create the desktop shortcut as well as setting the shortcut icon to the Control Panel icon, as per the conventional GodMod "new folder" method:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\Desktop\GodMode.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe"
$Shortcut.Arguments = "shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}"
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%SystemRoot%"
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll,21"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

To run the above, copy and paste all of the lines into a `Windows Powershell` window, and press the Return key (`↵`).